# How can I set a different default application to open those text files that end with the extension .edl?

Tags: file-management, file-manager

Essentially I want to "tell" Linux, "Every time I open a text file that ends with '.edl', please open that file with MPV (which is an application that plays videos)."

I have a text file named `foo.edl`. Currently when I double-click on `foo.edl` it is opened by `KWrite` (which is a text editor).

However, when I double-click on `foo.edl`—as well as any file with the `.edl` extension—I would like it to be opened by `mpv`.

See, I set KWrite (the "little brother" of the text editor named Kate) as the default application to open text files. Normally  when I double-click on a text file, I want text files to be opened by KWrite. But in cases that a text file ends with `.edl`I want those files opened with with mpv.

After reading [How to open different plain text files (.txt and .tex) with different default applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279463/how-to-open-different-plain-text-files-txt-and-tex-with-different-default-ap) I tried adding `text/x-edl=mpv.desktop;` to `~/.config/mimeapps.list` but that didn't solve my problem. Instead, doing that didn't seem to change anything.

In case you are curious, "EDL files basically concatenate ranges of video/audio from multiple source files into a single continuous virtual file." Source: [mpv/DOCS/edl-mpv.rst](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/edl-mpv.rst)

Comment: This is generally different per distro, so it would probably be an idea to add your Distro to this question.  As you're using KWrite and Kate, it sounds KDE based, so maybe check this out: https://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management#Change_a_File_Association_on-the-fly

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a suggestion. Actually I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (which of course, is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian). My hunch is that I might be able to solve my problem by modifying ~/.config/mimeapps.list.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate that. In that case, should I delete this question?